# Using pandas to select specific seasons from a dataframe whose values are over a defined threshold

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies for the wall of code, but I can't shorten it further...

I want to sample climate data based on extreme seasons (seasons with temperatures greater or less than two standard deviations) in a deterministic way, i.e. so I can select a warm season, followed by a cold season, or multiple warms followed by multiple colds etc.

The sample code below should illustrate the problem

Import the necessary packages

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
%matplotlib inline
```

Generate a dataframe with random values in a column

```
dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=18250)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(18250), columns = list ('A'))
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A']]
```

Define a season function and split data by season

```
def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return '1'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return '2'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return '3'
    else:
        return '4'

df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
```

If the month is December add 1 to the year value, so December January February are all in the same year

```
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df.loc[df['date'].dt.month == 12, 'Year'] += 1
```

Calculate season means

```
seasmean = df['A'].groupby(df['Season']).mean()
```

Multi-index a new dataframe by season and year

```
df2 = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)
df2.head()
df2.to_csv('df2.csv', sep = ',')
```

Calculate the differences between seasons and season means

```
seasdif = df2['A'].groupby(level=['Year','Season']).mean() - seasmean
seasdif
```

Visualise the seasonal differences and extremes based on standard deviations

```
seasdif.plot()
plt.axhline(0,color='red')
plt.axhline(seasdif.std() * 2, color ='red')
plt.axhline(-(seasdif.std()) * 2, color ='red')
```

It's clear from this that some seasons are above and below the 2 SD threshold, I want to be able to create a new deterministic sequence based on this, where I can select for example a normal spring followed by a hot summer followed by a hot autumn followed by a cold winter (or any permutations of this possible).

**EDIT**

This function finds warm and cold seasons and appends 0 if it's not extreme and 1 if it's extreme to warm and cold columns respectively

```
seasdif2 = pd.DataFrame(seasdif)
warm = []
cold = []

def extremeseas(seasdif):
    for season in seasdif:
        if season > seasdif.std() * 2:
            warm.append(1)
        else:
            warm.append(0)

    for season in seasdif:
        if season < (-(seasdif.std()*2)):
            cold.append(1)
        else:
            cold.append(0)
```

Apply the function to the dataset:

```
extremeseas(seasdif)
```

add columns to the new dataframe which identify extremes

```
seasdif2['cold']=cold
seasdif2['warm']=warm
seasdif2
```

I want to generate a new climate sequence based on this data, where I can specify what kind of climate I want, i.e. I want to be able to select 8 random seasons in a row, then select a random spring, followed by a hot summer, followed by a random autumn, followed by a cold winter.

I need to be able to select whatever sequence I want, so far all I've managed to do is select a random sequence for x amount of years (50 in this case) using the following code:

```
future = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(50):
    for season in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:
        future = future.append(df2.loc[np.random.choice(range(2007,2050))]
                                  .loc[season])
```

The problem is this selects a completely random sequence, which is good as I want a random sequence, but I also want to be able to insert extreme seasons/years into this sequence e.g. 20 random years with 3 extreme years or 10 random years followed by 3 years with cold winters etc. and can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for selecting a normal spring followed by a warm summer (just using 1 std dev, not 2, for this example).

```
>>> seasdif[ (abs(seasdif) < seasdif.std()) &                     # within 1 std dev
             (seasdif.index.get_level_values('Season') == '1') &  # spring 
             (seasdif.shift(-1) > seasdif.std()) ]                # following summer

Year  Season
2036  1         0.064691
2038  1        -0.016453
2047  1         0.020691
2053  1         0.063338
2055  1        -0.045606
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

My random data is different than yours, so here are my values for 2036 and the std dev below that so that you can verify what the code is doing.

```
>>> seasdif.loc[2036]

Season
1    0.064691
2    0.165824
3   -0.043372
4    0.086788
Name: A, dtype: float64

>>> seasdif.std()

0.09357005962032763
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates a dataframe that has your year, season, temperature, two flag columns for unusually hot and cold weather this season, and two flag columns for unusually hot and cold weather last season.

First, duplicate your dataframe, and add flags for unusual weather to the new dataframe:

```
seasdif2 = pd.DataFrame(seasdif)
warm = []
cold = []
for season in seasdif:
    if season > seasdif.std() * 2:
        warm.append(1)
    else:
        warm.append(0)

for season in seasdif:
    if season < (-(seasdif.std()*2)):
        cold.append(1)
    else:
        cold.append(0)

seasdif2['cold']=cold
seasdif2['warm']=warm
```

Then, drop your temperature column 'A', so that you have a "flags only" dataframe:

```
seasdif2 = seasdif2.drop('A',1)
```

Now, concatenate your flags to your original temperature dataframe. By shifting the index of the flags as you concatenate, you can flag whether the unusual weather happened last season as opposed to this season.

In this case, seasdif2 adds flag columns for unusually warm and cold weather this season, while seasdif2.shift(-1) adds columns for unusually warm and cold weather the previous season:

```
flagged_seasons = pd.concat([seasdif, seasdif2, seasdif2.shift(-1), seasdif2.shift(1)], axis=1)
```

Be careful when doing this, however, as you'll end up with multiple "warm" and "cold" flag columns. Make sure you rename the columns added by shift(-1) something like "cold_previous" and "warm_previous" respectively.

Now you can select rows where unusual weather occurred in two consecutive seasons. If you wanted to find whether a hot season is followed by cold season, you would just select dataframe rows where warm==1 and cold_previous==1, for example.

Comment: Thanks this really helps - I'm sorry for not being clearer, but I don't want to identify consecutive seasons which may have been extreme, I just want to identify the extremes (which I can do thanks to your help) and then create a new climate sequence containing these extremes (e.g. 10 'normal' climate years followed by a year with an extremely cold and wet winter, followed by a hot summer etc), so I need to work out a way of selecting the all the data within an extreme season and putting it in a dataframe with the sequence of 'normal' observations... Thanks again!