# Pandas define a seasonal year from June 1 - July 30 instead of Jan 1 - Dec 31

Tags: python, pandas

I have seasonal snow data which I want to group by snow year (July 1, 1954 - June 30, 1955) rather than having one winter's data split over two years  (January 1, 1954 - December 31, 1954 and January 1, 1955 - Dec 31, 1955.)

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp7Y1.png)

I modified the code from this question:

[Using pandas to select specific seasons from a dataframe whose values are over a defined threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793557/using-pandas-to-select-specific-seasons-from-a-dataframe-whose-values-are-over-a) (thanks Pad)

```
def get_season(row):
  if row['date'].month <= 7:
      return row['date'].year
  else:
      return row['date'].year + 1

df['Seasonal_Year'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
```

[results of method call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJwLo.png)

Is there a better way to do this than I have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think yes, with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
years = df['date'].dt.year
df['Seasonal_Year'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month <= 7, years, years + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `pd.offsets.MonthBegin`

Consider the dataframe of dates `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=pd.date_range('2010-01-30', periods=24, freq='M')))
```

We can offset the Date and grab the year

```
df.assign(Season=(df.Date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(7)).dt.year + 1)

         Date  Season
0  2010-01-31    2010
1  2010-02-28    2010
2  2010-03-31    2010
3  2010-04-30    2010
4  2010-05-31    2010
5  2010-06-30    2010
6  2010-07-31    2011
7  2010-08-31    2011
8  2010-09-30    2011
9  2010-10-31    2011
10 2010-11-30    2011
11 2010-12-31    2011
12 2011-01-31    2011
13 2011-02-28    2011
14 2011-03-31    2011
15 2011-04-30    2011
16 2011-05-31    2011
17 2011-06-30    2011
18 2011-07-31    2012
19 2011-08-31    2012
20 2011-09-30    2012
21 2011-10-31    2012
22 2011-11-30    2012
23 2011-12-31    2012
```